# why Angular 2 reset form is also rest array of object

Tags: angular

I build a simple angular app.I have a class and a from in html template matching with my object of class here is my component.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer, PeopleDependent } from '../Model/customer';
import { FormsModule, NgForm  } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({    selector: 'peopleFrom',    templateUrl: 'app/Components/PeopleFrom.component.html'})
export class PeopleFromComponent  {

constructor() {
    this.dependent = new PeopleDependent();
}

private dependentArray: PeopleDependent[]=[];
private dependent: PeopleDependent;  
private onPeopleDependentSubmit(frm: NgForm) {
    debugger;
    if (frm.form.valid) {
        //first way is not working??
        this.dependentArray.push(this.dependent);
        frm.form.reset() 

        //second way is working
        let newDependetn: PeopleDependent = new PeopleDependent();
        newDependetn.FirstName = this.dependent.FirstName;

        this.dependentArray.push(newDependetn);
        frm.form.reset() 
    }
}
}
```

and here is my html template

```html
<legend>People Dependent</legend>
<div class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onPeopleDependentSubmit(PeopleDependentForm)" #PeopleDependentForm="ngForm" ngForm  autocomplete="off" novalidate >
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group rqd">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="PeopleDependent_FirstName">FirstName </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control " id="PeopleDependent_FirstName" name="PeopleDependent.FirstName" #PeopleDependentFirstName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dependent.FirstName" type="text" value="" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group rqd">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="PeopleDependent_LastName">LastName</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control " id="PeopleDependent_LastName" name="PeopleDependent.LastName" #PeopleDependentLastName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dependent.LastName" type="text" value=""required >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group  rqd">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="PeopleDependent_BirthDate">BirthDate</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <dp-date-picker dir="rtl"
                                    id="PeopleDependent_BirthDate"
                                    name="PeopleDependent.BirthDate"
                                    [(ngModel)]="dependent.BirthDate"
                                    mode="day"
                                    placeholder="BirthDate"
                                    theme="dp-material"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    required
                                    #BirthDate="ngModel">
                    </dp-date-picker>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="PeopleDependent_Ratio">Ratio</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control " id="PeopleDependent_Ratio" name="PeopleDependent.Ratio" #PeopleDependentRatio="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dependent.Ratio" type="text" value="" >
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="PeopleDependent_Income">Income</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control " id="PeopleDependent_Income" name="PeopleDependent.Income" #PeopleDependentIncome="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dependent.Income" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group  ">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="PeopleDependent_Job">Job</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control " id="PeopleDependent_Job" name="PeopleDependent.Job" #PeopleDependentJob="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dependent.Job" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group  ">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="PeopleDependent_Education">Education</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control " id="PeopleDependent_Education" name="PeopleDependent.Education" #PeopleDependentEducation="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dependent.Education" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!PeopleDependentForm.form.valid" (click)="onPeopleDependentSubmit(PeopleDependentForm)">Create</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="PeopleDependentForm.reset()">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-striped" id="ListItemTbl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>row</th>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th>LasttName</th>
                    <th>BirthDate </th>
                    <th>Ratio</th>
                    <th>Education</th>
                    <th>Job</th>
                    <th>Income</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of dependentArray;let i = index;">
                        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.BirthDate}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Ratio}}</td>
                        <td> {{item.Education}} </td>
                        <td>{{item.Job}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Income}}</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i push to array with this syntax and reset the form, then object of array is also clear and it depends on instance of Class;

> this.dependentArray.push(this.dependent);        frm.form.reset()

Why this array has cleared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this comes from the fact that your form is bound to `this.dependent`.

You might have a reference problem here. Considering your form's refers to `this.dependent`, then when you call `form.reset`, you actually clear `this.dependent`.
This means that the `PeopleDependent` instance you are using is shared between your form and your array. It's actually the same object.

One solution might be to copy the form value before clearing.
You can try the following solution:

```
const dependantCopy = Object.assign(new PeopleDependent(), this.dependant); // copying current dependant into new PeopleDependent.
this.dependentArray.push(dependantCopy);
frm.form.reset()
```